# How to get the last char in an array with a binary search

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

My teacher wrote an algorithm to find a number in an array. I have tried to convert it to find a `char`.

If I search for the the first `char` of an array it works, but if I try to find the last `char` in the same array it gives me 0 or an unexpected number (like 100+, when the array is like 4 `char`s).

Here's the code:

```
int myIndex = binarySearch(sentence , word[0], 0, sentence.length -1);

char [] sentence = {'s','t','a','c','k','o','v','e','r','f','l','o','w'};
char [] word = {'o','v','e','r'};

static int binarySearch(char [] arr, char x, int l, int r){
    if(r<l){
        return 0;
    }

    int m = l+(r-l)/2;
    if(arr[m] == x){
        return m;
    }
    if(arr[m] < x){
        return binarySearch(arr, x, m+1, r);
    }
    return binarySearch(arr, x, l, m-1);
}
```

If I search for the first letter in the `word` array it works fine, but if I search for the last letter in the `word` array it breaks.

Comment: Binary search only works on sorted arrays but your sentence array is not sorted at all.

Comment: thank you, won't use it.

Comment: in addigion, correct binary search algo  must work fine with last or first place in array

Answer (score 1):

You are using a binary search on the input array `arr` of chars which is not sorted. So, you must first sort the array or use a linear search on the unsorted array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a sorted array to do a binary search.

For this,

add this line before you call search method : `Arrays.sort(sentence);`

Answer (score 0):

binary search that you are using only works on sorted arrays , besides this point your code is correct

you should sort the array first of all like this :
(by importing the java arrays)

```
import java.util.Arrays; 

Arrays.sort(array_of_chars);
```

Comment: That's not java

Answer (score 0):

This will work without sorting array.
Can you please try with this,

```
 int myIndex = binarySearch(sentence , 'w');



 static int binarySearch(char[] arr, char x) 
     { 
         int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1; 
         while (l <= r) { 
             int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 

             int res = String.valueOf(x).compareTo(String.valueOf(arr[m])); 

             // Check if x is present at mid 
             if (res == 0) 
                 return m; 

             // If x greater, ignore left half 
             if (res > 0) 
                 l = m + 1; 

             // If x is smaller, ignore right half 
             else
                 r = m - 1; 
         } 

         return -1; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For binary search to work, please **sort** the array first.

```
//import utility class
import java.util.Arrays;

//Make use of sort function to sort the array
Arrays.sort(sentence);

//Call binary search now
int myIndex = binarySearch(sentence , word[0], 0, sentence.length -1);
```